# Transform Table from Narrow Table to Wide Table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datatable

I have a problem when do some code :

```
df_transform = df_restohours.pivot_table(index='placeID', columns='days', values='hours', aggfunc='sum')
```

I want to transform table, from:

[image]

to :

[image]

I have tried to run that code, but I didn't get the table that I expected

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code in the question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Pandas has any builtin method to split a column name but you can accomplish your goal by looping through the columns.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

dd = {'placeID':[13511,13522],
      'hours':['00:00-23:22','00:00-23:33'],
      'days':['Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri','Sat;Sun']
      }

df_restohours = pd.DataFrame(dd)

df = df_restohours.pivot_table(index='placeID', columns='days', values='hours', aggfunc='sum')

print(df_restohours.to_string(index=False))

df = df.rename_axis(None,axis='columns')  # remove 'days' label
df = df.reset_index()  # move index to column

for c in df.columns:
   for c1 in c.split(';')[1:]:   # copy to new columns
       df[c1] = df[c]
df = df.rename(columns={c:c.split(';')[0] for c in df.columns})  # rename original

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
 placeID        hours                 days
   13511  00:00-23:22  Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri
   13522  00:00-23:33              Sat;Sun


 placeID          Mon          Sat          Tue          Wed          Thu          Fri          Sun
   13511  00:00-23:22          NaN  00:00-23:22  00:00-23:22  00:00-23:22  00:00-23:22          NaN
   13522          NaN  00:00-23:33          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  00:00-23:33
```